# mysql UPDATE for specific ordering, in one query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have a table of items, one of whose fields is a 'display order' field that controls the order in which the items will be displayed to the user. i would like to set all of the values of this field in the entire table to the value that would be obtained if the table were sorted by a specific set of criteria -- for example, alphabetically. **note - i cannot change the order of the table with `ALTER TABLE items ORDER BY item_name` for example ; the table must physically retain its original order.**

if we can assume the table `items` with a field `item_name` containing the item name and a field `disp_order` controlling display order, in essence what i'd like to do is this (for an alphabetical ordering) :

```
SET @i:=0;
UPDATE items SET disp_order=(SELECT @i:=@i+1 FROM items ORDER BY item_name);
```

obviously i can't do that because i'm modifying the table i'm selecting from. but is there some way i could do this in a single statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER BY` also applies to update query, so simply:

```
SET @i:=0;
UPDATE items SET disp_order=@i:=@i+1 ORDER BY item_name;
```